# Less bulky serenity-bdd console output

Tags: serenity-bdd

I was so annoyed by these bulky banners written to the output of serenity execution:

```
864 [main] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - 
 _____ _____ ____ _____   ____ _____  _    ____ _____ _____ ____  
|_   _| ____/ ___|_   _| / ___|_   _|/ \  |  _ \_   _| ____|  _ \ 
  | | |  _| \___ \ | |   \___ \ | | / _ \ | |_) || | |  _| | | | |
  | | | |___ ___) || |    ___) || |/ ___ \|  _ < | | | |___| |_| |
  |_| |_____|____/ |_|   |____/ |_/_/   \_\_| \_\|_| |_____|____/ 


TEST STARTED: myTest
```

I found this property `-Dserenity.console.headings=normal` and turned into this:

```
411 [main] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - 
----------------
- TEST STARTED -
----------------
TEST STARTED: myTest
```

Is there another way to not show this useless redundant `- TEST STARTED -` surrounded by dashes right before having `"TEST STARTED: myTest"` again?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: It can be turned off by adding the `serenity.console.headings=QUIET` property in your `serenity.properties` file (or by setting the system property directly).

**Note**: I have tested the same in latest serenity version i.e. 2.0.76 and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

There is the property `serenity.logging=QUIET` in [ThucydidesSystemProperty.java](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/bedf3d241a82c1ed91446a4d8c4d98090cca3be1/serenity-core/src/main/java/net/thucydides/core/ThucydidesSystemProperty.java#L723), but it apparently suppresses all logging from `net.serenitybdd`. Yes, the value must be "QUIET" in all caps... ;)

Comment: Original question: hide ---------------- - TEST STARTED - ---------------- but still show TEST STARTED: myTest

Comment: Question is too old. I'm not even using Serenity anymore. Maybe they already changed.